# different servers on different ports: friendly url?

Tags: redirect, port, url

I have different servers for different applications running on different ports and I want users to use friendly url to browse the applications. e.g.

- localhost:8080 run by tomcat -> I want users to use localhost/jira as url
- localhost:9000 run by python -> I want users to use localhost/confluence as url
- localhost:3600 run by nodeJS-> I want users to use localhost/app as url

and so on... applications should also be able to use SSL.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Look into running a reverse proxy on HTTP/HTTPS. There's lots of examples of how to do this with apache.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to do this?

Yes, the technology you are looking for is a [Reverse Proxy](https://serverfault.com/search?q=%22reverse%20proxy%22).